# Flashing a GUI button using Perl & Ttk on a Mac

Tags: perl, tkx

Using Perl v5.28, [Tkx.pm v1.10](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tkx) with
ActiveState Tcl/TTk v8.6.9 ('aqua' style), on macOS v10.13.6.  The
demo below works as desired, enabling the calling of a given
subroutine using either a GUI button push using the mouse, or using
keyboard input with a 'normal' text character.

The one additional feature I would like to have is the visual feedback
of the graphical button being pressed (flashing) when the keyboard
alternative activation is used.  I found what looks like a Tcl
solution using the [event
generate](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/event+generate) command, and
a reference on using the Perl
[Tkx::event_generate()](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/concepts.html#events)
virtual event method call.  I even found the equivalent Perl
`Tkx::after(100)` function call to create the suggested delay.  But I
can't wrap my head around how to put this all together to achieve the
desired effect.  Any help would be appreciated, with the understanding
that, like some other TTk features, this might not work on the Mac.

**CODE**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# -*- cperl -*-

use warnings;
use strict;
use Tkx; $Tkx::TRACE = 1;
my $mw = Tkx::widget->new(".");
$mw->g_wm_geometry('200x200+100+100');

my $l = $mw->new_ttk__label
  (
    -text => ("Button Test Ttk v" . Tkx::info("patchlevel"))
  );

sub greeting { print(STDERR "--> [ Hello, world ] pressed\n") }

my $b = $mw->new_ttk__button
  (
         -text => "Hello, world",
    -underline => 0,
      -command => sub { greeting() }
  );

$mw->g_bind('<h>', sub { $b->invoke() });
$mw->g_bind('<H>', sub { $b->invoke() });
$l->g_pack();
$b->g_pack();
Tkx::MainLoop();

print(STDERR "Program exit...\n");
```

**RUN LOG**

```
Tkx-1-0.0s-demo-12: wm geometry . 200x200+100+100
Tkx-2-0.0s-demo-14: info patchlevel
Tkx-3-0.0s-demo-14: winfo children .
Tkx-4-0.0s-demo-14: ttk::label .l -text {Button Test Ttk v8.6.9}
Tkx-5-0.0s-demo-26: winfo children .
Tkx-6-0.0s-demo-26: ttk::button .b -text {Hello, world} -underline 0 -command perl::callback
Tkx-7-0.0s-demo-28: bind . <h> perl::callback
Tkx-8-0.0s-demo-29: bind . <H> perl::callback
Tkx-9-0.0s-demo-30: pack .l
Tkx-10-0.0s-demo-31: pack .b
--> [ Hello, world ] pressed
Tkx-11-6.4s-demo-28: .b invoke
--> [ Hello, world ] pressed
Tkx-12-7.9s-demo-29: .b invoke
--> [ Hello, world ] pressed
Program exit...
```

Comment: I am not able to make `Tkx` work on macOS 11.2.3, see [this](https://github.com/chrstphrchvz/tkx/issues/3) issue.

Comment: I feel your pain.  I have specifically avoided moving past macOS High Sierra (v10.13) for my personal projects just to avoid issues like what you are seeing.  Since Apple is removing all the scripting languages, I'd recommend installing the ActiveState Tcl package.  At the bottom of the Perl Tkx module documentation is an environment variable you may need to define so that Tkx can find the ActiveTcl library.  I'm loving the 8.6 version of Ttk (themed Tk) which makes the Perl/Tk apps look native on the Mac.  It also has themes for various versions Windows, and Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example (tested on Ubuntu 21.04). By calling `g_event_generate("<ButtonPress-1>")` on the button, `invoke()` will be automatically called on the button:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tkx;
my $mw = Tkx::widget->new(".");
$mw->g_wm_geometry('200x200+100+100');

my $l = $mw->new_ttk__label(
    -text => ("Button Test Ttk v" . Tkx::info("patchlevel"))
);

sub greeting { say "--> [ Hello, world ] pressed"; }

my $b = $mw->new_ttk__button(
    -text      => "Hello, world",
    -underline => 0,
    -command   => sub { greeting() }
);
sub generate_button_click_event {
    $b->g_event_generate("<ButtonPress-1>");
    Tkx::after(
        200, sub {
            $b->g_event_generate("<ButtonRelease-1>");
        }
    );
}

$mw->g_bind('<h>', sub { generate_button_click_event() });
$mw->g_bind('<H>', sub { generate_button_click_event() });
$l->g_pack();
$b->g_pack();
Tkx::MainLoop();
say "Program exit...";
```